# How do I format Compile[] correctly?

Tags: warning-messages, special-functions, compile, summation

My Mathematica skill is still rusty, so kindly bear with me.

I'm having problem formatting expression to `compile` the function correctly:

$\sum _{g=1}^G \sum _{n=1}^{\text{Ns}} -\frac{e^{\frac{\text{Kg}}{P \gamma _{g,n}}} \text{Kg} \beta _{g,n}}{\text{Log}[2]} \text{ExpIntegralEi}\left[-\frac{\text{Kg}}{P \gamma _{g,n}}\right]$

All variables are known except $\beta_{g,n}$ which is an optimization variable. Here's what I've done to express it using`compile[]` function.

```
costFxn = 
 Compile[{{P, _Real}, {Ns, _Integer}, {gh, _Real}, {Kg, _Integer}, {G, _Integer}, 
 {\beta_{g, n}, _Integer}},

 Sum[-Exp[Kg/(P gh[[g,n]])](Kg \beta_{g,n})/Log[2] ExpIntegalEi[-Kg/(P gh[[g,n]])], {g,1,G},{n,1,Ns}]
  ]
```

when I try executing this snippet, I get part spec error.

```
'Compile::part: "Part specification gh[[1,1]] cannot be compiled since the argument is not a tensor of sufficient rank. Evaluation will use the uncompiled function."'
```

I've been rummaging through the help file but not quite sure of how to correct this error.

Comment: Notice that you've also spelt `ExpIntegalEi` incorrectly.

Comment: An update to this question has been posted here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60976/how-to-use-compile-in-numerical-optimization

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `gh` is a tensor, you need to say what rank it is, so replace `{gh, _Real}` with `{gh, _Real, 2}` to fix the error.

```
costFxn = Compile[
            {{P, _Real}, {Ns, _Integer}, {gh, _Real, 2}, 
             {Kg, _Integer}, {G, _Integer}, {betaGN, _Integer}}, 
            Sum[
              -Exp[Kg/(P gh[[g, n]])] (Kg * betaGN)/
                Log[2] ExpIntegralEi[-Kg/(P gh[[g, n]])], 
             {g, 1, G}, 
             {n, 1, Ns}]]
```

However, note that `ExpIntegralEi` is [not a compilable function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions), so will leave a call to `MainEvaluate` inside the compiled function.

That said, comparing the compiled and uncompiled versions, we find:

```
Do[costFxn[5, 2, {{5, 1}, {2, 3}}, 3, 2, 1], {1000}] // AbsoluteTiming
(* 0.009018 seconds *)

myCostFxn[P_, Ns_, gh_, Kg_, G_, betaGN_] :=
 N[Sum[-Exp[Kg/(P gh[[g, n]])] (Kg * betaGN)/
     Log[2] ExpIntegralEi[-Kg/(P gh[[g, n]])], {g, 1, G}, {n, 1, Ns}]]

Do[myCostFxn[5, 2, {{5, 1}, {2, 3}}, 3, 2, 1], {1000}] // AbsoluteTiming
(* 0.067047 seconds *)

costFxn[5, 2, {{5, 1}, {2, 3}}, 3, 2, 1]
(* = 23.4363 *)
myCostFxn[5, 2, {{5, 1}, {2, 3}}, 3, 2, 1]
(* = 23.4363 *)
```

So there is a benefit to compiling.

---

### Edit

If you mean for $\beta_{g,n}$ to be a variable that depends on the value of `g` and `n`, then you need to pass it as a tensor too.

```
costFxn2 = Compile[
            {{P, _Real}, {Ns, _Integer}, {gh, _Real, 2}, 
             {Kg, _Integer}, {G, _Integer}, {betaGN, _Integer, 2}}, 
            Sum[
              -Exp[Kg/(P gh[[g, n]])] (Kg * betaGN[[g,n]])/
                Log[2] ExpIntegralEi[-Kg/(P gh[[g, n]])], 
             {g, 1, G}, 
             {n, 1, Ns}]]

costFxn2[5, 10, RandomReal[{1, 3}, {3, 10}], 4, 3, RandomInteger[{1, 3}, {3, 10}]]
(* = 355.973 *)
```

Comment: Using artguments $P = 5; Ns = 10; G = 3; Kg = 4; gh = 
 RandomReal[\{1, 3\}, {G, Ns}]; \beta_{g,n}$ gives argument error: Argument <>...<> at position 3 should be a machine-size real number

Comment: That's probably because `RandomReal[1,3,G,Ns]` is incorrect syntax. If you want a matrix that has dimensions `G x Ns` than try `RandomReal[{1, 3}, {G, Ns}]`.

Comment: Try using `costFxn[5, 10, RandomReal[{1, 3}, {3, 10}], 4, 3, 1]` and you'll see that works.

Comment: Oh, I see the problem. Actually, I did $ RandomReal[\{1,3\},\{G,Ns\}]$. The copy pasting removed the formatting.

Problem is, since I'll be using the resulting equation as cost function, the $\beta_{g,n}$ should remain in the compiled function. If we replace last arg $1$ with $\beta_{g,n}$, same error occurs.

Comment: Ok, so there is a bigger reason for that - `Compiled` functions only accept Integers, Reals, Complex Numbers and Booleans. The documentation is here: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Compile.html - look under the "Details & Options" part. What you want to do is symbolic, which won't work.

Comment: If you're doing some form of numerical optimization, you can still use a compiled function to pass numerical guesses of $\beta_{g,n}$ to your function.

Comment: Exactly, `costFxn2` is actually the objective function to the optimization problem where the $\beta_{g,n}$ is the optimization variable, so it should remain.

There are also additional constraint equations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17520/discussion-between-afloz-and-blochwave).