# How to implement linear constraints in numerical optimization?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-algebra

I'm trying to wrap my head around function `Compile`. So, this is a spin-off question from: [a previous question on using compile[] correctly.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60958/how-do-i-format-compile-correctly)

I have a function that has been expressed as a compiled function. All variables are known except $\beta_{g,n}$ which is an optimization variable and should remain in the compiled function. Here's what I've done to express it using`Compile`.

```
compileCost = 
  Compile[{{P, _Real}, {Ns, _Integer}, {gh, _Real, 2}, 
   {usrK, _Integer,1}, {G, _Integer}, {betha, _Integer,2}},
    N[Sum[-Exp[usrK[[g]]/(P gh[[g, n]])] (usrK[[g]] betha[[g,n]])/
      Log[2] ExpIntegralEi[-(usrK[[g]]/(P gh[[g, n]]))]
      , {g, 1, G}, {n, 1, Ns}]
  ]]
```

When evaluated with the input:

```
P = 5; Ns = 7; G = 3; usrK = RandomInteger[{2, 5}, G]; 
gh = RandomReal[{1, 3}, {G, Ns}]; 
betha = Table[1, {g, G}, {n, Ns}];

compileCost[P, Ns, gh, usrK, G, betha]
```

> ```
> 101.298
> ```

Then I tried using this an a numerical optimization problem (removing the constraint functions for simplicity).

```
With[{variable = compileCost},
 fxnCompiledCost = Compile[{{P, _Real},{Ns, _Integer},{gh, _Real, 2},{usrK, _Integer, 1},
   {G,_Integer},{betha,_Integer,2}}, variable[P,Ns,gh,usrK,G,betha],
   "RuntimeOptions" -> {"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False},
   CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> False},
   Parallelization -> Automatic]
   ];

subcindexSet = Flatten[Table[\beta_{g, n}, {g, G}, {n, Ns}]];
NMaximize[fxnCompiledCost[P, Ns, gh, usrK, G, \beta_{g, n}], subcindexSet]
```

When I try executing this snippet, I get a not-a-number message.

> NMaximize::nnum: The function value -CompiledFunction ... is not a number at {...}

How do I move forward from here please?

I've followed examples from here: [Using compiled function inside NMinimize](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57354/using-compiled-function-inside-nminimize)

===============**Edit** =========

Actually there are constraint but I thought I could remove them to simplify my question:

```
 intConstRelax = Thread[0 <= subcindexSet <= 1];
 binaryConst = List[subcindexSet \[Element] Integers];
 nonShareConstr = Table[Sum[\beta_{g,n}, {g, 1, G}] == 1, {n, Ns}];
 constrSet = Join[nonShareConstr, intConstRelax, binaryConst];
```

===============**Edit** =========

Computation slows down considerably when I add one more constraint equation to the above:

```
 qosConstr = Table[Sum[\beta_{g,n} Log2[1 + (P/Ns) gh[[g, n]] ], {n,Ns}] >= constQ, {g, G}];
```

So constraint list now becomes:

```
 constrSet = Join[nonShareConstr, intConstRelax, binaryConst, qosConstr];
```

===============**Edit** =========

Thank you everyone for your help. Due to time difference I was not able to comment instantly on your questions. Some of the procedure are also a little bit over my head so I'm checking up on them. Thanks so much.

Comment: Do your constraints mean that **all** $\beta_{g,n}$ are either 0 or 1, and nothing else? If so, I've updated my answer a bit.

Comment: Yes. the constraints means 0 or 1. Just binary integer.

Comment: Ok, well look through the answers below!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Introduction

The update of the question invalidates my original approach, which depended on the problem being a simple special case.  The current problem consists of a linear objective function with linear constraints, to be maximized over the integers.  Theoretically, one can solve the problem with [`LinearProgramming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LinearProgramming.html).  In the OP's setup, the variables `betha` form a (rank-2) matrix instead of a rank-1 vector needed to use `LinearProgramming`.  One can flatten the problem out and use integer linear programming. Alternatively, one can do a brute-force search, which turns out to be faster in this case.

### Brute force is a little faster

Define the cost in terms of a memoized coefficient function `costCoeff`, and it turns out an exhaustive search of the possible inputs is at least twice as fast as `LinearProgramming`.  See further down for some discussion of the use of listability in the code for `costCoeff` etc.  For instance, `Times` automatically multiplies corresponding parts of lists and matrices.  Such properties allows us to rewrite the OP's code more efficiently in terms of the whole matrices and vectors instead of their parts.

```
constQ = 2;  (* not given -- made up *)
P = 5; Ns = 7; G = 3;
SeedRandom[1];
usrK = RandomInteger[{2, 5}, G];
gh = RandomReal[{1, 3}, {G, Ns}];

costCoeff[P_?NumericQ, Ns_?NumericQ, gh_?(MatrixQ[#, NumericQ] &), 
  usrK_?(VectorQ[#, IntegerQ] &), G_?NumericQ] :=
   costCoeff[P, Ns, gh, usrK, G] = -Exp[usrK/(P gh)] (usrK) / Log[2] ExpIntegralEi[-(usrK/(P gh))]

cost[P_?NumericQ, Ns_?NumericQ, gh_?(MatrixQ[#, NumericQ] &), 
   usrK_?(VectorQ[#, IntegerQ] &), G_?NumericQ, betha_] := 
  Total[costCoeff[P, Ns, gh, usrK, G] betha, 2];
```

We use `UnitStep[x - constQ]` to implement the OP's `qosConstr` constraints.  The values of `UnitStep` have be `1` on all rows for the constraints to be met; if one is not met, the minimum of the values will be `0`.  This criterion is used to [`Pick`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Pick.html) out of all the 0-1 matrices with exactly one `1` in each column, those that satisfy these constraints.

```
domain = Transpose[Tuples[Permutations[Append[ConstantArray[0, G - 1], 1]], 7], {1, 3, 2}];
domain2 = 
  Pick[
   domain, 
   Min /@ Transpose @
     UnitStep[Total[Transpose[domain, {3, 1, 2}] Log2[1 + (P/Ns) gh], {2}] - constQ],
   1];
betamax = domain2[[
   Last @ Ordering[cost[P, Ns, gh, usrK, G, Transpose[domain2, {3, 1, 2}]]]
   ]]
cost[P, Ns, gh, usrK, G, betamax]
(*
  {{0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}}
  41.9077
*)
```

### Linear programming is conceptually more natural

`LinearProgramming` minimizes its objective function.  To get a maximum we can take the negative of the OP's cost function.  Below, `costCoeff` represents the matrix of coefficients.  To maximize the cost function, I used `-Flatten @ costCoeff[P, Ns, gh, usrK, G]` for the objective function.  Each linear constraints is specified in two parts, a list of coefficients of the variables and a pair `{b, s}` representing a boundary value `b` and a code `s` -- `-1`, `0`, or `1` -- for the inequality as described in the documentation for [`LinearProgramming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LinearProgramming.html).  The second-to-last argument specifies the bounds on each variable to be `0` and `1`.

```
solFlat = LinearProgramming[
   -Flatten @ costCoeff[P, Ns, gh, usrK, G],           (* objective function *)
   Table[Flatten @ Transpose @                         (* one 1 in each column *)
       ReplacePart[ConstantArray[0., {Ns, G}], i -> ConstantArray[1, G]], {i, Ns}] ~Join~
    MapIndexed[                                        (* fourth constraint coeffs *)
     Flatten @ ReplacePart[ ConstantArray[0., {G, Ns}], #2 -> #1] &, 
     Log2[1 + (P/Ns) gh]],
   ConstantArray[{1, -1}, Ns] ~Join~                   (* constraint inequalities *)
     ConstantArray[{constQ, 1}, G],
   ConstantArray[{0, 1}, G*Ns],                        (* 0-1 constraint *)
   Integers
   ];
sol = Partition[solFlat, Ns]                           (* reshape into G x Ns matrix *)
cost[P, Ns, gh, usrK, G, sol]                          (* maximum cost *)
(*
  {{0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}}
  41.9077
*)
```

### Remarks and explanation

#### Objective function - listability and efficiency

To use *Mathematica* efficiently with matrices, vectors, and other arrays, it pays to learn how the[`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Listable.html) attribute (or more precisely, internal vectorization) and threading work with the numeric functions, including `Plus` and `Times`, as well as the importance of packed arrays (see [What is a Mathematica packed array?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array)).  Here are a few ways to compute the OP's cost function, the OP's way `costOP`, the way from the original answer `costME2`, and the way above `costFlat`.  They are equivalent.

```
costOP = Sum[-Exp[usrK[[g]]/(P gh[[g, n]])] (usrK[[g]] betha[g, n]) /
     Log[2] ExpIntegralEi[-(usrK[[g]]/(P gh[[g, n]]))], {g, 1, G}, {n, 1, Ns}];
costME2 = Total[costCoeff[P, Ns, gh, usrK, G] Array[betha, {G, Ns}], 2];
costFlat = Flatten@costCoeff[P, Ns, gh, usrK, G] . Flatten@Array[betha, {G, Ns}];
costOP == costME2 == costFlat
(* True *)
```

*Remark:* In computing the objective function, instead of using `Sum` and `Part`, one should use the listability of the built-in numeric functions, which *Mathematica* handles much more efficiently.  This would be an important point if the objective function were to be evaluated many times, as it would if `NMinimize` were used.  In the above `costCoeff` is evaluated only once.  If we turn them into functions, we can compare the timings:

```
ClearAll[costOP, costME2, costFlat];
costOP[betha_] := Sum[-Exp[usrK[[g]]/(P gh[[g, n]])] (usrK[[g]] betha[[g, n]])/
     Log[2] ExpIntegralEi[-(usrK[[g]]/(P gh[[g, n]]))], {g, 1, G}, {n, 1, Ns}];
costFlat[betha_] := Flatten@costCoeff[P, Ns, gh, usrK, G] . Flatten@betha;
costME2[betha_] := Total[costCoeff[P, Ns, gh, usrK, G] betha, 2];

SeedRandom[1];
testOP = Table[costOP[RandomInteger[1, {G, Ns}]], {1000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
SeedRandom[1];
testFlat = Table[costFlat[RandomInteger[1, {G, Ns}]], {1000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
SeedRandom[1];
testME2 = costME2[Transpose[RandomInteger[1, {1000, G, Ns}], {3, 1, 2}]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*
  {0.372749, Null}
  {0.130880, Null}
  {0.000734, Null}  <-- Wow.  Compare with the brute-force method above.
*)

testOP == testFlat == testME2
(* True *)
```

#### Constraints

The constraints are implemented in three pieces.

First, the lists

```
Table[Flatten @ Transpose @ ReplacePart[ConstantArray[0., {Ns, G}], i -> {1, 1, 1}], {i, Ns}]
```

together with

```
ConstantArray[{1, -1}, Ns]
```

specify the column sums should be at most 1.

Second, the lists

```
MapIndexed[
  Flatten @ ReplacePart[ConstantArray[0., {G, Ns}], #2 -> #1] &, 
  Log2[1 + (P/Ns) gh]]
```

together with

```
ConstantArray[{constQ, 1}, G]
```

specify the row sums with the coefficients from the corresponding row of the matrix `Log2[1 + (P/Ns) gh]` should be at most `constQ`.

Third, the argument

```
ConstantArray[{0, 1}, G*Ns],                        (* 0-1 constraint *)
```

specifies that each variable should be between 0 and 1 (inclusive), and the final argument `Integers` specifies that the variables are to be integers.

#### Timing

The `AbsoluteTiming` of the brute-force method is `0.001875` sec.
The `AbsoluteTiming` of the `LinearProgramming` code is `0.004235`, which is more than twice as long as the brute-force method.

---

### Original answer

First, your objective function is linear in your variables `betha`, which form a matrix in your setup.

Second, your constraints imply that an input is a 0-1 matrix with exactly one entry being 1 in each column. *Edit note: the OP later added a constraint that makes the following not apply to the current question.*

The fastest way to maximize the function is to pick among each column of coefficients, the position of the maximum coefficient and set the corresponding variable to 1 (and set the others in the column to zero, of course).

```
Transpose @
 Map[ReplacePart[ConstantArray[0, G], # -> 1] &, 
  Last /@ Ordering /@ Transpose @ costCoeff[P, Ns, gh, usrK, G]
  ]
cost[P, Ns, gh, usrK, G, %]
(*
  {{0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}
  42.5
*)
```

**A check**

A simple check is to evaluate the function on all possible inputs and take the max.

```
domain = Transpose[
   Tuples[Permutations[Append[ConstantArray[0, G - 1], 1]], 7], {1, 3, 2}];
domain[[
  Last @ Ordering[cost[P, Ns, gh, usrK, G, Transpose[domain, {3, 1, 2}]]]
  ]]

(*
  {{0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}
  42.5
*)
```

Comment: hadn't thought of this, nice!

Comment: Your heuristic approach is quite interesting and Yes, your understanding of the problem is spot-on. 

My current (extended modified version of the problem) is super slow and I'm guessing this approach should be faster.

I notice your current suggestion does not include the constraints. Would you consider updating with the constraint please? I've added four constraints in my edited question.

Comment: wooow. Lots of heavy stuffs going on here. I'm taking 'em a bit at a time. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: Amazing stuffs. I don't know who you are but I'll buy someone a cup of coffee on your behalf! Thank you for putting so much work and explanation into this.

Comment: @Afloz, Thank you very much. *Mathematica* much more efficiently deals with numeric arrays as arrays. Learning to think in those terms takes time; at least it did for me. Here are some simple examples to play with. For threading, compare how `Times` works in `{2, 3, 5} {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}`, `{2, 3} {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}}` and `{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}} {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}`. For transposing multiple levels, let `mat = Table[a[i] b[j] c[k], {i, 2}, {j, 3}, {k, 4}]; matT = Transpose[mat, {3, 1, 2}]`, and figure out why these are the same: `mat[[1, 3, 4]]` and `matT[[3, 4, 1]]`.

Comment: Thnkx for the tip. Will check it out. Meanwhile, I'm trying to understand the significance of the list `{1,1,1}` in `ReplacePart[ConstantArray[0., {Ns, G}], i -> {1, 1, 1}]` for the first constraint.

Comment: @Afloz After `Transpose`, that results in a column of ones. The corresponding constraint is that `beta[1, i] + beta[2, i] + beta[3, i] <= 1`. Since each variable `beta` is either a 0 or a 1, it means there will be one 1 and two 0's in the column.  (I realize now that the code for `{1, 1, 1}` should be `ConstantArray[1, G]`.  I had missed that until you asked, so thanks!)

Comment: Ah. that's it. `{1,1,1}` was an example of `G = 3`. Awesome stuffs. Thanks so much.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Allow me to ask a little more details about the `Transpose`. Yes, it's a little more involved to understand. I see that the specification of `{1, 3, 2}` and `{3, 1, 2}` in `Transpose` depends on the value of `G`. Do you think there's a way to generalize the order of level `kx` in `Transpose[list, {k1, k2...}]` for arbitrary `G` in this problem?

Comment: @Afloz, I don't think `{3, 1, 2}` depends on `G` (unless I made a mistake somewhere). The basic input for `betha` is a `G x Ns` matrix, a rank-2 array. A set of inputs like `domain` is a list of such matrices, or a rank-3 array. It's rank 3 because it takes three integers to specify an element: `domain[[i, j, k]]`. Each integer refers to a part of a level: `i` is part `i` of the first level, `j` refers to the second level (part `j` of part `i`), etc. `Transpose` rearranges the array so as to change the levels. `{3, 1, 2}`: level `1` becomes level `3`, level `2` becomes `1`, `3` becomes `2`.

Comment: @Afloz  I think you can see where `G` appears by comparing `Dimensions@domain2` (= `{516, 3, 7}`) and `Dimensions@Transpose[domain2, {3, 1, 2}]` (= `{3, 7, 516}`). The first `Transpose` is because the `Tuples` code creates a list (level 1) of `Ns x G` matrices (levels 2, 3); however, we want a list of `G x Ns` matrices, so levels 2, 3 have to be switched. (If the system asks whether to continue in chat, feel free to say yes.  Comments aren't really meant for such long explanations.)  Cheers

Comment: I get your points. 
Wondering how the constraints invalidate your original approach. I thought after selecting and setting the maximum coeff per column, we could search over the columns for those satisfying the constraints.

*Sidenote*: The brute force approach is a big memory hog even for small values. Larger values  of `P=25, Ns=16  G=5, constQ=2` crashes my quadcore i7 CPU, 10GB RAM.

Comment: Was refering to the `Transpose`, `Permutation` methods

Comment: @Afloz The original approach was based on the assumption that the maximum was to be found over all possible inputs with exactly one 1 in each column.  That implies that an input with a 1 in the row corresponding to the greatest coefficient is possible.  With the restricted domain, such an input might not be possible.  And, yes, `domain` takes about `G * Ns * G^Ns * 8` bytes of memory, or over 97 TB for `Ns=16, G=5`!

Answer (score 3):

So we have a couple things going on here.

First, as mentioned in an answer to your previous question, `ExpIntegralEi` is not compilable (`MainEvaluate` called). So speedup from compiling this function will be negligible and it may be easier to not even compile in this case.

Second, to properly use `NMaximize` we need the function to accept numeric arguments only. Since some arguments are lists, we have to get a little creative on how we specify argument patterns. We can define the function as such:

```
compileCost[P_?NumericQ, Ns_?NumericQ, gh : {{_?NumericQ ..} ..}, usrK : {_?NumericQ..}, 
            G_?NumericQ, betha : {{_?NumericQ ..} ..}] :=
    N[Sum[-Exp[usrK[[g]]/(P gh[[g, n]])] (usrK[[g]] betha[[g, n]])/Log[2] 
    ExpIntegralEi[-(usrK[[g]]/(P gh[[g, n]]))], {g, 1, G}, {n, 1, Ns}]]
```

This ensures that the function will only evaluate for lists of certain dimensions that contain only numeric values.

Third, `NMaximize` is not being set up properly. We can adjust like so:

```
subcindexSet = Table[Symbol["betha" <> ToString@g <> ToString@n], {g, G}, {n, Ns}];
NMaximize[compileCost[P, Ns, gh, usrK, G, subcindexSet], Flatten@subcindexSet]
```

Without constraints, the function seems to be unbounded. Also, a word of caution that global minimization/maximization becomes very unwieldy, especially when guessing so many variables.

Answer (score 3):

### Edited answer

If I reinterpret your constraints so they make sense,

```
constraints = Apply[And, 
       Flatten@{
            Apply[LessEqual, {0, #, 1}] & /@ Flatten@subcindexSet, 
            Map[Total@# == 1 &, Transpose@subcindexSet, {1}]
       }]

(*
 0 <= betha11 <= 1 && 0 <= betha12 <= 1 && 0 <= betha13 <= 1 && 
 0 <= betha14 <= 1 && 0 <= betha15 <= 1 && 0 <= betha16 <= 1 && 
 0 <= betha17 <= 1 && 0 <= betha21 <= 1 && 0 <= betha22 <= 1 && 
 0 <= betha23 <= 1 && 0 <= betha24 <= 1 && 0 <= betha25 <= 1 && 
 0 <= betha26 <= 1 && 0 <= betha27 <= 1 && 0 <= betha31 <= 1 && 
 0 <= betha32 <= 1 && 0 <= betha33 <= 1 && 0 <= betha34 <= 1 && 
 0 <= betha35 <= 1 && 0 <= betha36 <= 1 && 0 <= betha37 <= 1 && 
 betha11 + betha21 + betha31 == 1 && 
 betha12 + betha22 + betha32 == 1 && 
 betha13 + betha23 + betha33 == 1 && 
 betha14 + betha24 + betha34 == 1 && 
 betha15 + betha25 + betha35 == 1 && 
 betha16 + betha26 + betha36 == 1 && 
 betha17 + betha27 + betha37 == 1
*)
```

However, I'm struggling to understand what you mean by restricting `subcindexSet` to be between 0 and 1, and then setting them all to be integers. Do you mean they are all equal to 0 or 1, and can therefore take no other values?

I guess you could redefine the function with an `_?IntegerQ` for `betha`,

```
compileCost[P_?NumericQ, Ns_?NumericQ, gh : {{_?NumericQ ..} ..}, 
  usrK : {_?NumericQ ..}, G_?NumericQ, betha : {{_?IntegerQ ..} ..}] :=
  N[Sum[-Exp[usrK[[g]]/(P gh[[g, n]])] (usrK[[g]] betha[[g, n]])/
     Log[2] ExpIntegralEi[-(usrK[[g]]/(P gh[[g, n]]))],
     {g, 1, G}, {n, 1, Ns}]]
```

Then run it with the same constraints as given above, and do a little bit of magic-trickery, because I can't seem to get it to work with $\in$ `Integers` properly.

Similarly, restricting to `(betha11 == 0 || betha11 == 1) && ...` in the constraints seems to take forever, compared to this fudge(?).

```
resultrules = FindMaximum[
                  {compileCost[P, Ns, gh, usrK, G, subcindexSet], constraints}, 
                  Flatten@subcindexSet, WorkingPrecision -> 18];

resultunrounded = subcindexSet /. Last@resultrules
(* 
{{1.58489319246111726*10^-14, 1.58489319246111726*10^-14, 
  0.999999999999984151, 1.58489319246111726*10^-14, 
  0.999999999999984151, 0.999999999999984151, 
  0.999999999999984151}, {0.999999999999984151, 0.999999999999984151, 
  1.58489319246111726*10^-14, 0.999999999999984151, 
  1.58489319246111726*10^-14, 1.58489319246111726*10^-14, 
  1.58489319246111726*10^-14}, {1.58489319246111726*10^-14, 
  1.58489319246111726*10^-14, 1.58489319246111726*10^-14, 
  1.58489319246111726*10^-14, 1.58489319246111726*10^-14, 
  1.58489319246111726*10^-14, 1.58489319246111726*10^-14}} 
*)

result = Round@subcindexSet /. Last@resultrules
(* {{0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}} *)
```

Does this seem like a correct solution?

---

### Original answer

As @kale mentions, you need constraints. Otherwise, look what happens when I use `FindMaximum` (rather than `NMaximize`, for this example).

```
P = 5; Ns = 7; G = 3; usrK = RandomInteger[{2, 5}, G];
gh = RandomReal[{1, 3}, {G, Ns}];
betha = Table[1, {g, G}, {n, Ns}];

compileCost[P_?NumericQ, Ns_?NumericQ, gh : {{_?NumericQ ..} ..}, 
  usrK : {_?NumericQ ..}, G_?NumericQ, betha : {{_?NumericQ ..} ..}] :=
  N[Sum[-Exp[usrK[[g]]/(P gh[[g, n]])] (usrK[[g]] betha[[g, n]])/
     Log[2] ExpIntegralEi[-(usrK[[g]]/(P gh[[g, n]]))], {g, 1, G}, {n, 1, Ns}]]

subcindexSet = Table[Symbol["betha" <> ToString@g <> ToString@n], {g, G}, {n, Ns}];

FindMaximum[compileCost[P, Ns, gh, usrK, G, subcindexSet], Flatten@subcindexSet]    
(* {1.97295*10^59, 
 {betha11 -> 3.44624*10^57, betha12 -> 2.26929*10^57, 
  betha13 -> 3.28037*10^57, betha14 -> 2.17458*10^57, 
  betha15 -> -5.88154*10^56, betha16 -> 4.10653*10^57, 
  betha17 -> 2.87052*10^57, betha21 -> 1.21735*10^57, 
  betha22 -> 1.00252*10^57, betha23 -> 7.45909*10^56, 
  betha24 -> 2.4225*10^57, betha25 -> 2.67294*10^57, 
  betha26 -> 3.08175*10^57, betha27 -> 5.92319*10^56, 
  betha31 -> 3.30424*10^57, betha32 -> 2.08312*10^57, 
  betha33 -> 1.4828*10^57, betha34 -> 1.68492*10^57, 
  betha35 -> 1.46808*10^57, betha36 -> 1.67782*10^57, 
  betha37 -> 3.11295*10^56}} *)
```

And as a further example,

```
constraints = Apply[And, Apply[LessEqual, {#, 100.}] & /@ Flatten@subcindexSet]
(*
 betha11 <= 100. && betha12 <= 100. && betha13 <= 100. && 
 betha14 <= 100. && betha15 <= 100. && betha16 <= 100. && 
 betha17 <= 100. && betha21 <= 100. && betha22 <= 100. && 
 betha23 <= 100. && betha24 <= 100. && betha25 <= 100. && 
 betha26 <= 100. && betha27 <= 100. && betha31 <= 100. && 
 betha32 <= 100. && betha33 <= 100. && betha34 <= 100. && 
 betha35 <= 100. && betha36 <= 100. && betha37 <= 100.
*)

FindMaximum[{compileCost[P, Ns, gh, usrK, G, subcindexSet], constraints}, 
      Flatten@subcindexSet]    
(* {9372.77,
 {betha11 -> 100., betha12 -> 100., betha13 -> 100., 
  betha14 -> 100., betha15 -> 100., betha16 -> 100., betha17 -> 100., 
  betha21 -> 100., betha22 -> 100., betha23 -> 100., betha24 -> 100., 
  betha25 -> 100., betha26 -> 100., betha27 -> 100., betha31 -> 100., 
  betha32 -> 100., betha33 -> 100., betha34 -> 100., betha35 -> 100., 
  betha36 -> 100., betha37 -> 100.}} *)
```

And as a comparison of timing,

```
FindMaximum[{compileCost[P, Ns, gh, usrK, G, subcindexSet], 
   constraints}, Flatten@subcindexSet]; // AbsoluteTiming
NMaximize[{compileCost[P, Ns, gh, usrK, G, subcindexSet], 
   constraints}, Flatten@subcindexSet]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* FindMaximum: 0.84 seconds *)
(* NMaximize: 2.86 seconds *)
```

Comment: I guess the $\in$ operator, binary restrictions on $\beta_{g,n}$ and formatting of my constraints seems to be what makes my code run for forever. Appears `FindMaximum` is faster because is `Local` right? I'm wondering if you did a comparison on optimal value in addition to the time comparison in the last step. Maybe I can consider results of `FindMaximum` an approximation if they are close enough.

Comment: The optimal results came out the same with `FindMaximum` and `NMaximize` when I ran it, but of course this is not always the case because the former is a local optimizer.